# object sharing bevel after joined

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I have one object with 1 bevel modifier and second with 2 bevel modifier, when I join both (ctrl j) the 2 bevel changes bevel to the first one...

is there any way for each individual object keep their bevel modifier after joined?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once several objects are joined they will discard their modifiers and inherit those on the **last selected object** so it's not possible to join objects with modifiers on them and keep them unique, but you can limit the the modifier to a certain  vertex group :

- Join the objects
- Assign each object to a vertex group
- Add two Bevel modifiers
- Set each modifier to effect only one vertex group

[image]